# How can I select rows into N groups per value of a certain column?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table in the form

```
Span     Available     Time
A            0          0
B            1          0
C            1          0
A            1          1
B            0          1
C            1          1
...         ...        ...
A            1          N
B            0          N
C            1          N
```

I want to group this into groups of X `Time`s per `Span`. So it would look like:

```
Span     Available     Time
A            1           0
A            0           1
...         ...         ...
A            1           X
B            1           0
B            1           1
...         ...         ...
B            0           X
C            0           0
C            1           1
...         ...         ...
C            0           X
A            1          X+1
A            0          X+2
...         ...         ...
A            1          2X
B            1          X+1
B            1          X+2
...         ...         ...
B            0           2X
...         ...         ...
...         ...         ...
A            0          N-X
A            1          N-X+1
...         ...         ...
A            0           N
B            1          N-X
B            0          N-X+1
...         ...         ...
B            1           N
C            0          N-X
C            1          N-X+1
...         ...         ...
C            1           N
```

Where `X` is a factor of `N`.

How can I group the data in this way using SQL *or* Spark's DataFrame API?

Also, how can I aggregate that table by X rows per span to get, for example, the percentage availability for the span from time 0 to X, X to 2X, etc.?

edit:

For context, each group of X rows represents a day, and the whole data set represents a week. So I want to aggregate the availability per day, per span.

edit:

Also, I know what X is. So I want to be able to say something like `GROUP BY Span LIMIT X ORDER BY Time`

edit:

As a final attempt to describe this better, I want the first X of the first span, then the first X of the next span, and then the first X of the last span, followed by the next X of the first span, the next X of the second span, etc., through to the last rows for each span.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I simple do not understand what you are trying to do. I get that yo have a table reflecting availability (0 or 1) at certain times (0 to N), but I don't understand the grouping. Could you maybe provide a simple example with real values or try to provide a more detailed description?

Comment: I want to group it into N/X groups, where each group contains a group of `X` values for each Span `A`, `B`, and `C`. I'll update the OP now.

The first group would go from 0 to X for A, then for B, then for C. The next group would go from X to 2X for A, then B, then C. this continues until X reaches N. N is a multiple of X.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand now :) Is the Time column a timestamp like "2015-09-24 15:01:23" or what does it look like?

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt it's a Java timestamp, something like 13456600000.

Comment: @RoryByrne if you have a Java timestamp you should be able to use the solution I have just posted as an answer.

Comment: Could you either accept one of the answers or explain why these doesn't work for you so these can be improved? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumption that your time column contains a timestamp and you input data thus looks something like this example rdd:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(("A", 0, "2015-01-02 09:00:00"),
                              ("A", 1, "2015-01-02 10:00:00"), 
                              ("A", 1, "2015-01-02 11:00:00"),
                              ("B", 0, "2015-01-02 09:00:00"),
                              ("B", 0, "2015-01-02 10:00:00"), 
                              ("B", 1, "2015-01-02 11:00:00"),
                              ("A", 1, "2015-01-03 09:00:00"),
                              ("A", 1, "2015-01-03 10:00:00"), 
                              ("A", 1, "2015-01-03 11:00:00"),
                              ("B", 0, "2015-01-03 09:00:00"),
                              ("B", 0, "2015-01-03 10:00:00"), 
                              ("B", 0, "2015-01-03 11:00:00")
))
```

you could achieve your grouping and aggregation like this:

```
rdd.map{case(span,availability,timestamp) => ((span,getDate(timestamp)), (List((availability, time)), availability, 1))}
  .reduceByKey((v1,v2) => (v1._1 ++ v2._1, v1._2 + v2._2, v1._3 + v2._3))
  .mapValues(v => (v._1, v._2.toDouble/v._3))
```

(Where `getDate()` is some function that will return the date from a timestamp.)

This will produce output in the format of (span, List((availability, time)), availability_percentage). For my example rdd the result will look like this:

```
 (B,List((0,2015-01-02 09:00:00), (0,2015-01-02 10:00:00), (1,2015-01-02 11:00:00)),0.3333333333333333)
 (A,List((0,2015-01-02 09:00:00), (1,2015-01-02 10:00:00), (1,2015-01-02 11:00:00)),0.6666666666666666)
 (A,List((1,2015-01-03 09:00:00), (1,2015-01-03 10:00:00), (1,2015-01-03 11:00:00)),1.0)
 (B,List((0,2015-01-03 09:00:00), (0,2015-01-03 10:00:00), (0,2015-01-03 11:00:00)),0.0)
```

Comment: While this is very useful, I'm having trouble getting the data from the form in the table at the top of the OP to the form that you're starting from here.

Comment: I see. I assumed that the data was in a parquet or csv file. Where is the data stored?

Comment: I just realised that you asked for how to do this using the DataFrame API. You should go for the solution posted by @zero323 then.